# Session timeout ASP.NET MVC4 with external login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, facebook-login, google-signin

I have this site (ASP.NET, MVC4) which uses external logins (Facebook and Google) from the template.

Everything works ok, but I'd like to add an option to logout the user automatically after let's say a day or so if the user chooses to, because right now, as long as the user is logged into google or Facebook, the user is automatically logged in, which is good, but I'd like to give the option to logout automatically, or to "Forget" the user.

Thank you in advance.